# Select Distinct result on top but return all result

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, rank, partition

I have a table with below structure and data ...

```
email      name address
abc@a.com  ab    us
abc@a.com  de    fr
xyz@x.com  bv    dc
efg@e.com  cd    mm
xyz@x.com  bv    dc
efg@e.com  cd    mm
```

I want to display the distinct rows based on email on top. For example in above case result should be:

```
email      name address
abc@a.com  ab    us
xyz@x.com  bv    dc
efg@e.com  cd    mm
abc@a.com  de    fr
xyz@x.com  bv    dc
efg@e.com  cd    mm
```

I am using the below query but it will only get me the distinct result and I need all rows with distinct on top

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY email ORDER BY email DESC) AS RowNumber, email, name address where RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Please provide a query that you have created.

Comment: I guess you want to use row_number() over (partition by email order by whatever) then order by that?

Comment: just edited the question and used row_number but how to use order by to get distinct results on top

Answer (score 3):

The easy way... Just use ROW_NUMBER in the ORDER BY clause...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    email VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [name] CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    [address] CHAR(2) NOT NULL 
    );

INSERT #TestData (email, [name], [address]) VALUES
    ('abc@a.com', 'ab', 'us'),
    ('abc@a.com', 'de', 'fr'),
    ('xyz@x.com', 'bv', 'dc'),
    ('efg@e.com', 'cd', 'mm'),
    ('xyz@x.com', 'bv', 'dc'),
    ('efg@e.com', 'cd', 'mm');

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #TestData td
ORDER BY 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY td.email ORDER BY td.[name]);
```

Comment: Another way but little too much for doing this `Sum(1) OVER (PARTITION BY td.email ORDER BY td.[name] rows between unbounded preceding and current row)`